# How can I include a ouija board in an RPG scene?

Tags: gm-techniques, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

I’d like to incorporate a ouija board in an RPG scene. (Campaign specific detail: using one allows PC’s to hack into the GodMachine’s network to ask for specific information). I plan to adapt the storyline to the random answers produced.

Has anyone tried this? Any advice?

Comment: Are you saying that the Ouija board will exist in the game world, or in the real world.

Comment: This is less related to your question, and more the situation: Are you sure that it won't upset anyone? A number of people have very strong feelings about Ouija boards, even within the gaming community.

Comment: @goodguy5 I wouldn’t use it if any players felt uncomfortable with the idea. Good point!

Comment: @goodguy5 I would use a real world board.